# Motion in a smooth vertical circle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I was reading some material on vertical circular motion and I was wondering if it was possible to find the the time period of the mass given that it completes the  full loop. Assume that the particle is launched  with an initial velocity $u$ from the  lowest point  of the vertical circle. I was  initially tempted to write $T=2\pi r/u$. But then I feel that this is that this is not uniform circular motion, so how should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail on the set up?  What is moving in a circle?  How is it constrained etc.?

Comment: See another answer [**here**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634148/solving-differential-equation-describing-motion-in-a-pendulum/1634177#1634177)

Answer (score 2):

You can use conservation of mechanical energy (or Lagrange's equations) to find the equations of motion and  you will arrive at 
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2=\frac{g}{r}\left(\cos\theta-1\right)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{u^2}{r^2},$$
where $\theta$ is the angular position of the the particle with respect to the vertical, and $\theta=0$ at the bottom of the circle. This is the same result you would get for a pendulum swinging through large angles.

Rearranging, you would get
$$\int\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\left(\frac{2g}{r}\left(\cos\theta-1\right)+\frac{u^2}{r^2} \right)^{1/2}}=\int \mathrm{d}t.$$

The integral on the left is related to a class known as elliptical integrals, which don't have a closed-form solution. They are solved by numerical methods. In your case, you would chose a value for your initial velocity, $u$, and numerically integrate the left side from $0\to 2\pi$, and that would give you the time for a complete circle.